# Grab file urls from multi file input[type="file"]

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input which accepts multiple files, on change (whenever a file is selected with the input), I want to grab the url of the images, so I can loop through each and update some `<img>` tags elsewhere on the page to preview the images you’ve uploaded.

I’ve managed to do this with another input which is single file only, not so much for multiple yet. Here is my single file input approach which works, then the details of the approach so far for the input which has `multiple` on.

This is the working single file input

```
// Function to process the image url from the input.
function read_featured_image_URL(input) {
  console.log(input.files);
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    $('#featured-image-preview-thumb-wrap').show();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('.featured-image-preview-thumb').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

// On change of input (when file selected) run the function to update the <img src="">
$(document).on("change", "#featured-image-input", function(){
  read_featured_image_URL(this);
});
```

THIS IS THE CONSOLE LOG RESULT OF console.log(input.files);

```
FileList {0: File, length: 1}
0: File {name: "single-toilet-roll-holder-2.jpg", lastModified: 1576627618564, lastModifiedDate: Wed Dec 18 2019 00:06:58 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 91672, …}
length: 1
__proto__: FileList
```

Now, this is me trying to get the same input.files data for a file uploaded to the input which accepts multiple files.

For starters I am simply checking if I have any data from the input:

```
$(document).on("change", ".additional-images-input", function(){
  read_multi_file_input(this)
});

function read_multi_file_input(input) {
  console.log(input);
  console.log(input.files);
}

// CONSOLE LOG RESULT:
```

As you can see, it's returning 0 results. In my testing, I have selected 1 image via the input and get no results back.

```
<input id="html5_1dseu9ccnu7a19ag13lc1j7a1nj33" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,.jpg,image/png,.png" class="additional-images-input">

FileList {length: 0}
```

This is the multi file input element:

```
<input id="html5_1dseu9ccnu7a19ag13lc1j7a1nj33" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,.jpg,image/png,.png" class="additional-images-input">
```

Comment: So create a loop.

Comment: As mentioned, I am getting a return of 0, so currently there is nothing to loop through.

Comment: What do you want as output?

Comment: *Note:* You don't need the content of this file, so you don't want to "read" it and you don't want a FileReader. Since what you want is to link to it so that the <img> (and not your script) can display it, create a link that points to it. To do so, use the synchronous [`URL.createObjectURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) method and you'll save yourself from useless callback nightmares along with saving a lot of memory from your users' devices.

Comment: Ps: I did vote to close as missing an [mcve], not as duplicate. Please try to make one where we can also experience the same issue, you can make use of [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/) to create runnable snippets in your question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop in JavaScript:

```js
// Function to process the image url from the input.
function read_featured_image_URL(input) {
  console.log(input.files);
  var max = input.files.length;
  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    if (input.files && input.files[i]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      $('#featured-image-preview-thumb-wrap').show();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('.featured-image-preview-thumb').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
}

// On change of input (when file selected) run the function to update the <img src="">
$(document).on("change", "#featured-image-input", function(){
  read_featured_image_URL(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple name="myfiles[]" id="featured-image-input">
```

Comment: Answer seems very flawed. First it is only one image, second you are only every loading the first image.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would not get any files. Basic tests show that it works. Below is showing how to use forEach to get to each file selected. It also generates an image for each file.

```js
function read_featured_image_URL(files) {
  // clear out any old images
  var outElem = $("#output").html('') 
  // convert the file list into an array
  Array.from(files)
    // loop over the array of files
    .forEach( function (file) {
      // create a new file reader
      var reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        // create an image element and set the source
        var img = $("<img />", { 'src': e.target.result })
        // add the image to our output element
        outElem.append(img)
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    })
}

$(document).on("change", "#featured-image-input", function(){
  read_featured_image_URL(this.files);
});
```

```css
#output img {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple name="myfiles[]" id="featured-image-input">

<div id="output"></dov>
```

if you want to use a for loop.

```js
function read_featured_image_URL(files) {
  // clear out any old images
  var outElem = $("#output").html('') 
  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    // reference the file in the current index
    var file = files[i]
    // create a new file reader
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      // create an image element and set the source
      var img = $("<img />", { 'src': e.target.result })
      // add the image to our output element
      outElem.append(img)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}

$(document).on("change", "#featured-image-input", function(){
  read_featured_image_URL(this.files);
});
```

```css
#output img {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" multiple name="myfiles[]" id="featured-image-input">

<div id="output"></dov>
```